# using js for auto upload file PDF with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php code like this

```
//this have loop for repeat data by $i
<tr>
  <th>Num:</th>
  <th>upload</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $i?></td>
  <td>
    <div id="me<?php echo $i ?>" num="<?php echo $i ?>" class="styleall me" ><span ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open uploadChange"></span></span></div><span id="mestatus<?php echo $i ?>" class="mestatus" ></span>
    <div id="files<?php echo $i ?>" class="files">
        <li class="success">
        </li>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr> // end loop
```

And this is my script

```
$('.uploadChange').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var num = $('.me').attr('num');
    var btnUpload = $('#me'+num);
    var mestatus = $('#mestatus' + num);
    var files = $('.files');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: '/uploadDoc.php',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
            if (!(ext && /^(pdf)$/.test(ext))) {
                mestatus.text('PDF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
            mestatus.html('<img src="/ajax-loader.gif" height="16" width="16">');
        },

        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            mestatus.text('File Uploaded Sucessfully!');
            files.html('');
        }
    });
});
```

This is code I follow by [this](http://scriptime.blogspot.in/2012/12/simple-ajax-image-upload.html)

my code can upload and run smooth for only first row element of data.
my problem is when I click next row element it is not execute in block:

```
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: '/uploadDoc.php',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
            if (!(ext && /^(pdf)$/.test(ext))) {
                mestatus.text('PDF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
            mestatus.html('<img src="/ajax-loader.gif" height="16" width="16">');
        },

        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            mestatus.text('File Uploaded Sucessfully!');
            files.html('');
        }
 });
```

please help me to review it for my code can procees upload a file PDF all row element data, thanks.